# jqplot dynamically get height of the Bar

Tags: jqplot, bar-chart

I'm trying to get a height of each bar in the Bar Graph for jQplot. So that I can change the color of x-axis label based on that height.

Can anyone help how to get the height dynamically?

Comment: Can you post a code sample of what you have?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is to base your color choice on the value of each bar. This way you don't have to browse your plot in order to find the height of each bar as you can only browse your data.